# Function in C++ that can either return something, or nothing

Tags: c++, methods, operator-overloading

I'm using a class

```
class list
{
    int val;
    list *next;
}
```

I want to overload the [] operator. This is what i've come up with:

```
int & operator [](int n)

{
    list *p;
    p=this;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        p=p->next;
        if(p==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"Index out of range ";
            return ?? ;
        }
    }

    return p->val;
}
```

I'm interested to know if there is a way to return nothing in case the index is out of range since the type of the value returned is int&.

Answer (score 2):

If the "index is out of range", this indicates a major internal logic problem in the code.

For this situation, in C++ you can throw an exception, to indicate an exceptional situation. Although there is a certain school of thought that frowns upon use of exceptions, they are a key part of C++, and there's nothing wrong with using exceptions, where appropriate.

If, on the other hand, your application does not consider an index out of range to be an internal logical fault, and it might very well be an expected error condition that should be handled normally, one way to handle this would be for your `operator[]` to return a utility object that has a boolean flag or a suitably named function such as `error()` and an `operator int()` overload. Thusly, the users of `operator[]` are now responsible for figuring out how to handle the error condition.

Answer (score 1):

Possible options:

- use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional - probably most elegant and modern-cpp-way
- prepare "empty object" as static member of your class and return
  reference to it (you can also return return pair with object and boolean variable with information if result is correct )
- return pointer to element and nullptr when no
  result (reather bad option)

Comment: *"probably most elegant and modern-cpp-way"* - More importantly, it's the wrong way. If a function cannot deliver it's promise, you throw an exception. Don't turn a simple rule into an over-engineered mess, using all the bleeding edge tools you have, just because you can.